Does answering any math questions you encounter help the quality of what you learn?
I'm an undergraduate math student and I'm trying to maximize the quality of what I could learn.
My strategy a few years ago started by just reading multiple concepts and topics from different fields and math, skipping most if not all the problems I'd encounter.
Years went by and I realized how I'm missing out alot by not solving problems. The thing I'd do now instead is(or atleast I'm trying) immerse myself through different kinds of problem and Problem sets, then try to hammer away.
Problem sets from either after a chapter from a book or a random one from google.

Could I just take any Problem sets and focus on just solving those?
Would what I learn be the same if I tackled any other Problem sets?
Would I miss out more if I just focus on one Problem sets?
What if I felt like I'm not learning anything new anymore from computational(problems)/applying-formula ones? Should I move on or am I bound to learn something new from doing these computational problems

Answers for any of these questions would greatly help. Thanks in advance!
PS: I ask these because they're more about the strategy on how I would be able to have a more quality self-study routine in the absence of a mentor(I dont have one besides the teacher for clarifications in class)

As student, why not concentrate on the stuff in you lectures. If you have more time, why not take one or two additional courses and do the exercises the give? (I don't know what P-sets are)

By P-sets, I meant problem sets

This reminds me of an oldish thread in Math.SE.

Yes, solving problems is probably the best way to go. Unless you're actually not interested in learning math and only interested in having cool stuff to say at parties; in that case, you can get away with just reading a lot of math stuff without solving any problems. But if you want to learn something you need to solve the problems.

I guess it wasnt more about whether I should do problems or not, but more on how would I routine myself corresponding to the questions above. But the input was still nice @Stef. The old thread helps alot too

"Problem sets  after a chapter from a book" are a must, if you want to really comprehend the Math in the book.
or a random P_s one from google will not help you. Concentrate on the problems closely connected to the math you are just studying.

How would it differ from a pset that I find from google? wouldnt it just be the same when i'm learning a single overarching concept?

You said a P-set from google so I supposed a random set, if it is set  to the theme of the chapter  you are studiing it is ok.

Well it sorta is of what I meant as long as it is a single topic per se. Random P-set from a google of a topic. How wouldnt that help me though? like for example linear algebra P-set from india or MIT. How would it differ from Pset to Pset?
